# JavaScript: how do I put a Promise in an object?

Tags: javascript

The code below attempts to create a promise and assign it to an element in an object, and then call `bar` when the promise is fulfilled. However, the `app.tabs.then` doesn't work ("Cannot read properties of null (reading 'then')"). Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
const app = {
   tabs : null,
   ...
};

document.getElementById('myid').addEventListener('click', function() {
   app.tabs = foo();  // returns a Promise
});

app.tabs.then(function() {
   bar();
});
```

**EDIT**

These are great answers, thanks, but there's an issue: when I now get to function`bar`, the promise has been fulfilled, and the `PromiseResult` is an array with one element, as expected. However, I can't actually read the result. I normally read `tabs[0].id` from `foo` (when I run different versions of this code with `async`). Element 0 of `PromiseResult` contains an object named `id`, but I can't read this as `app.tabs[0].id` - the debugger just says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')". Any idea why?

Comment: `app.tabs` is undefined until the `click` is raised. You can't call `.then` on it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing this particular `Promise` (being in an event handler, and thus you're in the middle of asynchronous things already) is just strange, you could rather store its result, something like

```
document.getElementById('myid').addEventListener('click', function() {
   foo().then(function(result) {
      apps.tab = result;
      bar();
   });
});
```

Because whenever you'd need its result, you'd have to `then()` it anyway.

Of course in 2023 you can probably use `async`, no contemporary browsers should complain about it:

```
document.getElementById('myid').addEventListener('click', async function() {
   apps.tab = await foo();
   bar();
});
```

Or even use an arrow function:

```js
const apps = {
  tab: null
};

const foo = () => new Promise(resolve => resolve(42));

document.getElementById('myid').addEventListener('click', async() => {
  apps.tab = await foo();
  bar();
});

function bar() {}
```

```html
<button onclick="alert(apps.tab);">Check</button>
<button id="myid">Clicky</button>
```

Click <kbd>Check</kbd> to see the initial `null` content, then <kbd>Clicky</kbd>, then <kbd>Check</kbd> to see the `42`.

Comment: Thanks - hadn't realised you could `async` the click handler. I also hadn't realised that I would have to do a two-level `then` to get the value out (see my edit; I ended up with a fulfilled promise, not a value). Still not really clear on this, though.

Answer (score 1):

`app.tabs` only changes when you click on that element, so it's null by the time the code that attaches `.then` is executed.

The best way to go about it is to attached the continuation right when the promise is created:

```
document.getElementById('myid').addEventListener('click', function() {
   app.tabs = foo();  // returns a Promise
   app.tabs.then(function() {
      bar();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('myid').addEventListener('click', function() {
   app.tabs = foo();  // returns a Promise

   app.tabs.then(function() {
      bar();
   });
});
```

This code attaches the .then callback to the app.tabs Promise within the click event listener, ensuring that bar() will be executed when the Promise is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed @Wiktor Zychla 
Untill the click event happens, `app.tabs` equals to `null` 
it's not possible to add property for that object. You can simulate a click event:

```
document.getElementById('myid').addEventListener('click', function() {
   app.tabs = foo();  // returns a Promise
 });

 document.getElementById('myid').dispatchEvent(new Event("click"))
```